# majorTicksColor by interval into dojox gauges using dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo

I'm trying to use dojo toolkit and exactly this [gauge](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/gauges/GlossyCircularGauge.html#dojox-gauges-glossycirculargauge).

In fact, I want a feature to majorTicksColor and minorTicksColor, I want the color  depends for the interval, eg :  from 0 to 30 green, from 30 to 70 yellow and from 70 red to 100, or maybe it is degraded.

Like this [image](https://www.targetdashboard.com/nlimages/badgauge.jpg).

Is that possible ?

Thank you.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsmfg/3/)?

The principal here is to use an aspect to enhance the `drawRange` method of the [`dojox/gauges/GlossyCircularGauge`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/gauges/GlossyCircularGauge) widget.

```
//
// Use the new "drawGreenYellowRedCurves" as an *after* aspect to the existing "drawRange" function.
//
require(['dojox/gauges/GlossyCircularGauge', 'dojo/aspect', 'drawGreenYellowRedCurves', 'dojo/domReady!'],
  function (GlossyCircularGauge, aspect, drawGreenYellowRedCurves) {
    var gauge = new GlossyCircularGauge({
        background: [255, 255, 255, 0],
        title: 'Value',
        id: "glossyGauge",
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }, dojo.byId("CircularGauge"));
    aspect.after(gauge, "drawRange", drawGreenYellowRedCurves, true);
    gauge.startup();
});
```

[image: Image of gauge]

Comment: Is that possible in the horizontal gauge ?
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/RTday/)  Thank you.

Comment: I added a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683164/adding-indicator-into-the-horizontal-gauge-using-dojo-toolkit).